# Read Matrix from a file to Octave

Tags: matrix, octave, svd

I'm trying to read a matrix from a file to Octave and then apply a svd. As example, the following matrix in a text file called "teste.txt":

```
1   3   -2  3
3   5   1   5
-2  1   4   2
```

I'm trying to execute the following script in octave:

```
data = dlmread ("teste.txt", "\t",0,0);
svd(data)
```

However, I'm facing the following error, which I don't know exacly why:

```
/home/thiago/Documents/svd.oct: invalid ELF header
error: called from:
error:   /home/thiago/Documents/svd.oct at line 2, column 1
```

Does anybody have any clue? I'm executing it on Ubuntu 14.04 and the file separator is a tab(\t).

Thank you very much in advance,

Thiago.

Comment: I guess you are getting the same error without dlmread, for example svd(hilb (3)), right? This sounds like some installation problem. How did you install it? Apt-get?

Comment: Which line does it error on? The `dlmread` line or the `svd` line? Have you checked the contents of `data`?

Comment: Btw, what is the source of /home/thiago/Documents/svd.oct? I just realized that this doesn't look like the svd which ships with Octave, right? Have you copied this from another machine/build?

Comment: In fact, I looked at this link to make this code above. http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/svd.html when I create a matrix inside the code with those numbers, the svd executes normally.  Therefore, I believe it's a problem with the reading from the file, as it says invalid header, but my for has no header.

Comment: One more thing, when I try to print the matrix data, it seems normal with 4 columns and 3 rows.